# Can't get Sublime Text 2 plugins to work (uncanny ERROR)

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I just installed ST2 and CoffeeScript plugin via Package Manager, but every plugin action is throwing the following issue to the console log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 356, in run_
  File "./CoffeeScript.py", line 90, in run
  File "./CoffeeScript.py", line 32, in brew
  File "./CoffeeScript.py", line 22, in run
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried the same with alternative plugins before, and the same error were still happening. Diggin the web for it, I saw this error being reported for other distinct plugins, although none of the posts was clearly pointing out a final solution.

I've done this before and it was working indeed, the only changes I recently made to this system was creating a new user for the mac and uninstalling ST2 to try out ST3. After some other incompatibility issues with version 3 I downgraded it again to the latest ST2 version.

OSX Mavericks here, running Python 2.7.5, and ST2 seems to run 2.6.8. I don't know Python, neither I know if this can be the issue's origin. I'm kinda lost, can anybody land me a hand on that?

Thanks very much.

Comment: You can check the version your system is using with `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])'`.

Comment: Hi indivisible, thanks for helping. The suggested command prints `(2, 7, 5, 'final', 0)` in OSX Terminal, inside ST2 it prints `(2, 6, 8, 'final', 0)`. Isn't this the same information we have above?

Comment: Ok, so your System path finds python 2.7 yet Sublime uses 2.6? Odd. Did you run as the user you are trying to install ST for? Do you have a custom shortcut or startup script? I'd suggest you remove ALL traces of SublimeText 2 & 3 (including any residual preference/settings in your home folders) and then install just one of them again from a new, clean download. Also, what were the issues you had with ST3?

Comment: [Here's a quick guide](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2132) to specify the version of python that SublimeText uses itself. I'd try to point directly to the 2.7 install first. I think it configures the version the plugins and console uses maybe not necessarily ST itself you could do that by customising your shortcut/make a start up script. (FYI, I'm using ST3 with python 3.3 and never have issues but I guess I don't have many plugins installed)

Comment: I've done all I could to remove traces from the previous ST3 instance, but yet I don't know if it is the origin of the problem. I'd suppose that my last install of ST2 was nice and clean. I uninstalled ST3 because the plugins I use were not yet available/ported. I'll try checking up your guide and post back soon.

Comment: Try combining the steps in the guide for manually setting the plugins' python version and also start ST2/3 with the exact same version from console with `/path/to/pythonXX/python /path/to/sublime_text/sublime_text`. Perhaps the plugin and app version need to match? If it works you can modify your shortcut or throw it in a script and link to that. (I'm linux guy, not Mac so not sure exactly how but know it's *nix so similar enough)

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened but I found out that coffeescript had just vanished from `/usr/local/bin/`. Should it be due to the creation of a second user on this machine? I just installed it again through Node Package Manager and it started working again. It's funny because before I got Coffeescript installed without Node.js or `npm`.
Well, the Python versions seems not to be the issue here.. but thanks anyway indivisible!

Answer (score 0):

Coffescript binaries were not available/installed in the system. So the issue was solved by following the [installation steps](http://coffeescript.org/#installation).

Comment: Haha, that'll do it alright! Glad you got it sorted in the end.